# Show continuity using analitycal definition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

I want to prove that the function in $\mathbb{R}^+$:

$$f(x)=x^{1-\alpha}-x$$

for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, is continous using the "epsilon-delta" definition of limit. To do this, I try to show that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)=x_0^{1-\alpha}-x_0$ in the following way:

For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$. Trying to find this $\delta$ I have manipulated this former expession to obtain:
$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|x^{1-\alpha}-x_0^{1-\alpha}-(x-x_0)|$$
$$\leq |x^{1-\alpha}-x_0^{1-\alpha}|+|x-x_0|$$
$$\leq |x^{1-\alpha}-x_0^{1-\alpha}|+\delta$$

but I am not sure on how to further bound $|x^{1-\alpha}-x_0^{1-\alpha}|$. Any advice? Thanks a lot!

Comment: For a real exponent $1-\alpha$, the continuity of $x \mapsto x^{1-\alpha}$ is somehow granted by definition. How do you define a power with real exponent?

Comment: What's the domain of f?

Comment: @AaronMaroja  $\mathbb{R}^+$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By factoring $x_0>0$, it is enough to analyze the continuity at $x=1$. So you want to work with $|x^{1-\alpha}-1|$ for $x$ close to $1$ (this is not essential, but it simplifies any computation a little bit).

I don't think you can get this bounded by (a multiple of) $|x-1|$ by algebraic methods. A key issue is how you even define $x^{1-\alpha}$. The standard way is to define 
$$
x^{1-\alpha}=e^{(1-\alpha)\log x}.
$$
The continuity then follows from the continuity of the logarithm and the exponential. We can get concrete estimates this way: if you write $x=1+d$, with $d$ small, then 
\begin{align}
x^{1-\alpha}-1&=e^{(1-\alpha)\log (1+d)}-1=e^{(1-\alpha)(d-o(d^2))}-1
=(1-\alpha)(d-o(d^2))+o(d^2)\\ \ \\&=(1-\alpha)d+o(d^2).
\end{align}
But getting to this level of explicit estimates requires dealing with Taylor expansions (or, at least in this case, with the Mean Value Theorem), while the continuity of $\log$ and $\exp$ is a more basic fact.